# FullCalendar start & end dates parsing as null when fetching events

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

When fetching the events from my database, the start and end date that full calendar parses to the controller is always null. Does anybody know why this is or how I can fix it?

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'prev,next today'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        weekends: false,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        eventDurationEditable: false,

        events: "/Event/GetEvents/"
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(double? start, double? end)
{
    var eventList = new List<object>();

    var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
    var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

    return Json(eventList.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have had to put the start and end dates as allowed to be nullable - denoted by the '?', but I shouldn't have to do this as I want to use the start and end values. However, as I mentioned they always get parsed as null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you saying that the start and end parameters are null? If so create a class that has a start and end, then reference that model in the parameter GetEvents(NewModel nm) - also post the code where you are sending those parameters to your controller

Comment: `events:` passes dates (in the ISO format `yyyy-MM-dd`), not doubles. Change your method to `public JsonResult GetEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)

Comment: @StephenMuecke realised I was following an outdated tutorial where the calendar used unix time stamps, as this is no longer the case, you are correct - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by Stephen, this was a very simple fix and easy mistake. As I was following an old guide the parameters for the get method have changed. Previously, they were doubles as they were in Unix format and needed to be converted. Now, they are of a DateTime format, so my resolution was:

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
{
    var eventList = new List<object>();

    var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
    var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

    return Json(eventList.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```